# database creation statement with jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

In our Java project we have started to use jooq for query building instead of plain SQL strings. The library is awesome, but I have a question (since I am jooq-newbie): Is it possible to create database using jooq, but WITHOUT PROJECT INCLUDED jooq mapping/generator?

Comment: Do you mean to generate code, or do you mean to create a database?
(jOOQ has no formal support for DDL, but you can still use plain SQL
commands to execute DDL). Do you mean you wouldn't include jooq-meta and jooq-codegen?

Comment: We want to create a database via invoking stored procedure.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. It is very hard to answer this question. See the [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for more details

Comment: I think that author mean if he can skip http://www.jooq.org/tutorial.php#step2 this step, so he could define table/column names as a string

Comment: @skowron-line: Maybe, although I'm still not sure how they want to "create a database" with jOOQ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot that you can do with jOOQ without relying on its code generator. The getting started guide from the manual mentions some examples:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder/

For instance:

```java
String sql = create.select(
                      fieldByName("BOOK","TITLE"), 
                      fieldByName("AUTHOR","FIRST_NAME"), 
                      fieldByName("AUTHOR","LAST_NAME"))
                   .from(tableByName("BOOK"))
                   .join(tableByName("AUTHOR"))
                   .on(fieldByName("BOOK", "AUTHOR_ID").equal("AUTHOR", "ID"))
                   .where(fieldByName("BOOK", "PUBLISHED_IN").equal(1948))
                   .getSQL();
```

It also references to the manual's section about using jOOQ for "plain SQL":

http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/

Of course, you can still use the code generator to generate meta information for your schema. This doesn't mean that you will have to add a runtime dependency on the generator, as the generator is only used at compile-time

Comment: This might sound stupid but, where is the method definition of `fieldByName`? I'm using `jooq 3.0.1` and I found out that `fieldByName` can actually be found in `Factory` class in lower versions. But when I switch to lower version (2.6.4), I can't use the `DSL` class.

Comment: @onepotato: Here's the 2.x -> 3.x migration guide: http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/reference/migrating-to-3.0. The method is right there, in [`DSL.fieldByName()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#fieldByName(java.lang.String...))